# ES6Promise not defined with VSTS SDK

Tags: javascript, typescript, tfs, promise, azure-devops

I have begin to work on VSTS widget (for TFS in my case). I could create/build/deploy them, and it works great.

But I am stuck with a problem, the SDK "VSS.SDK.min.js" call Promise.js and create an error when calling `ES6Promise.polyfill();`
[image]

I have created my widgets in Typescript and the calls are made with require.js.

To resolve my problem I have tried to include "es6-promise" in my project, include it in the call, set it to Auto-polyfill (with `require('es6-promise').polyfill();`) but the problem is still here.

My tsconfig.json is set with

```
"compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es5",
   "module": "amd",
   "lib": [
     "es5",
     "es6",
     "dom",
     "es2015",
     "es2015.promise" /* should be useless since es2015 is already here */
   ], 
   "strict": true,  
   "types": [
      "vss-web-extension-sdk",
      "requirejs",
      "jquery",
      "es6-promise"
   ],
```

It's not an error that block me because the problem only appears on the debug console, but an error is still and error.

As `VSS.SDK.min.js` is running on the server, I am wondering if the problem is in my widget or if a configuration is missing on the TFS server.

I have the error on "IE11 / Chrome / FF".

Any help would be welcome and if you need any more information to give me a hint, I will gladly upgrade my question.

**update**

The problem seems to be on the call `VSS.require("TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers", function (WidgetHelpers) {`

Maxime

Comment: Strange.. I've build multiple widgets and I've never had to include any es5/6 or promise stuff.  Countdown Widget is  open sourced at https://github.com/ALM-Rangers/Countdown-Widget-Extension Can you try to run that one and see if you get the same problems? Is your extension open sourced? If so, I can try to run it and see if I can fix the error.

Comment: Sadly it's a private widget for my company and the calls are highly dependants of our database. But this morning I found the problem appear when i call `VSS.require("TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers", function (WidgetHelpers) {`

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? If so, can you share the sample project on the OneDrive?

Comment: What's the version of your TFS Server? Does the issue occur if you deploy the extension on VSTS?

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT we have the latest version of TFS and the problem occurs when the widget/hub is deploy. The problem is on the require() call

Comment: @MaximePorté I created a sample extension base on this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-dashboard-widget which used "VSS.require("TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers", function (WidgetHelpers)" but cannot reproduce this issue at my side. Can you share a sample project?

Comment: right now github is not cooperative. I have create a sample project that reproduce the problem, as soon as github agree with me I upload it and add the link to it. Thanks for the help